# WebClient bad request 400 on valid url

Tags: c#, steam-web-api

Im trying to access this url "http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=us&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Black%20Laminate%20(Minimal%20Wear)".

It works in my browser in chrome, but not in IE for some reason. Furthermore it doesnt work in my code:

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            w.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36");
            w.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DK&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Black%20Laminate%20(Minimal%20Wear)");
            }
```

json_data is always just an empty string. I thought it had something todo with missing UserAgent, but adding the header did not help. What do you guys think could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: It's a bad request on all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid URL. Try running it through Postman or another REST tool and you'll see that no matter what it returns 400 Bad Request. Chrome just happens to display the `[]` in the browser instead of displaying an error message. Have you applied for a Steam API key?

http://steamcommunity.com/dev

It's rare that an API will allow public access without requiring that you include a token with your request. I don't see anywhere in your code where you're attaching it so I'm going to assume no. I suggest you sign up for their program.

Comment: Wow... I really had myself convinced something with the code was wrong.. The reason it works in chrome is becuase im logged in on steams website..
Thank you for the help

Comment: feel free to mark this as answered if it solves your problem